# VSCode: How to bind a keyboard shortcut to a setting.json entry

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a configured a Docker Compose Up recipe in my `.vscode/settings.json` file.  How can I bind a keyboard shortcut to execute this recipe?

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.classpath": true,
        "**/.project": true,
        "**/.settings": true,
        "**/.factorypath": true
    },
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "docker.commands.composeUp": [
        {
            "label": "Stack description",
            "template": "docker-compose -p test -f aa.yml -f bb.yml up -d --build"
        },
```

Comment: what is the normal way to execute this composeUp

Comment: Right-click a docker-compose file, select "Compose Up", select the desired label from the popup menu.

Comment: that means there is a particular command in that extension that is executed and maybe set a parameter to do the `Compose Up`, search the exposed commands on the extension page